# Devbridge Autocomplete, no result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, jsonp

I am trying to use the [DevBridge jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) with AJAX support.

I have created all the required parts but the plugin is not giving me any result.
The console does not give me any error.

```
function initializeSubjectAutocomplete()
{
    /* Add field */

    realSubjectSelector = $('#containerForm select#subject');
    realSubjectSelector.hide();
    realSubjectSelector.after('<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subjectAutocomplete" name="subjectAutocomplete">');

    /* Autocomplete */

    $('#containerForm input#subjectAutocomplete').autocomplete(
        {
            serviceUrl: 'getAutocompleteThreads',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            minChars: 3,
            onSelect: function (suggestion){realSubjectSelector.val(suggestion.data);}
        }
    );
}
```

A typical result of my getAutocompleteThreads is formatted like that :

```
{
query: "resolvi",
suggestions: [
    { value: "Not resolving Symlinks at all", data: "13102" },
    { value: "Resolving inter-library dependencies", data: "12079" },
    { value: "Resolving static lib dependency at executable link time", data: "13098" },
    { value: "help needed in resolving this pipeline problem", data: "59531" },
    { value: "Resolving coincident faces - linear & quadratic quarilaterals", data: "68186" }
]
}
```

Thank you for your time,

Felix

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not giving time for the DOM to be updated from when you insert `#subjectAutocomplete` to then just executing `autocomplete()` on it.

Try replacing your following code:

```
realSubjectSelector.after('<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subjectAutocomplete" name="subjectAutocomplete">');

    /* Autocomplete */

    $('#containerForm input#subjectAutocomplete').autocomplete(
```

for this one:

```
$('<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subjectAutocomplete" name="subjectAutocomplete">').insertAfter(realSubjectSelector).autocomplete(
```

Comment: Has not changed anything ! The function was definite in $(document).ready(), so I think DOM was ready.

But maybe I have to precise that the the page is dealing with a lot of result, up to 100,000.